# Given two directories, how can I know which subdirectories differ?

Tags: bash, directory, compare, diff, patch

I had two directories, `directory` and `directory.original`. I want to know which sub-directories are different to create a patch from each different directory instead one big patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that maybe it's not the more elegant way, works great when you are trying to patch some source code:

```
diff -qr directory directory.original | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs dirname | uniq
```

Let's study this code for a second:

- `diff -qr dir dir.original`: compares both directories with the brief flag (`-q`), that makes diff doesn't output the actual diff, but instead just post the files. The `-r` is to make the diffing recursive into its subdirectories.
- `cut -d' ' -f2`: The default output of `diff -qr` is something like:

  > `Files dir/file1 and dir.original/file1 differ`
  >
  > `Files dir/sub-dir/file2 and dir.original/sub-dir/file2 differ`
  >
  > `Files dir/sub-dir/file3 and dir.original/sub-dir/file3 differ`

  Using the `cut` command you choose the delimiter to be a space (`-d' '`), and then you pick the second field, in this case `dir/file1`.
- `xargs dirname`: Run the `dirname` command for each "line" so you can strip the filename. Now you have `dir`, `dir/sub-dir`, `dir/sub-dir` (since there were 2 different files in that subdirectory).
- `uniq`: If there are more than one different (sub)directory, just list one.

You have to be careful when actually creating the patch, remember that you should not use the `-r` flag on the root (`dir/`) because you will create a big patch.

```
directories=$(diff -qr directory directory.original | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs dirname | uniq)
for dir in $directories; do
  subdirectory=$(basename $dir)
  echo "+ $dir"
  diff -Naur directory.original/$subdirectory directory/$subdirectory > ${$subdirectory}.patch
done
```